# How to copy the code shown in my webpage with a button embedded in it

Tags: javascript, html

```
function copy() {
    var x= document.getElementById("content");
    x.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');  
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
}
```

this is the js code that i used to select and copy the content of input.

what to do if i want to add a button on my webpage to select some div and copy the shown code in clipboard.

Comment: call this function on button click??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just using the dummy input method:

```js
function copy() {      
  const text = document.getElementById("copyDiv").innerText;
  const elem = document.createElement("input");
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
  elem.value = text;
  elem.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(elem);
  document.write("Copied to clipboard!");
}
```

```html
<div id="copyDiv">Text to be copied</div>
<button onclick="copy()">Copy text</button>
```

Comment: of course we can select it ,by creating element , but i want to know , that is there any direct method to select the content of div

Answer (score 0):

here i figured out the solution of my own problem.
Html:

```
<div id="divid" onclick="copy('divid')">Division to be copied</div>
```

js:

```
function copy(i)
        {
         var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNode(document.getElementById(i));
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
        window.getSelection().addRange(range); 
        document.execCommand('copy');
}
```